# acer aod 270-1466 get more video memory any possible way

Tags: windows-7, laptop, graphics-card, bios, upgrade

is there any possible way to get more megabytes to my graphics card. 
its a quad core. 1.6ghz, i got 4g ram stick windows 7 ultimate bios been updated and as far as i know the only thing left is bigger hard drive. how can i get better graphics performance, basicaly more then 8mb or so it says. id like to get atleast 128mb for the video. awesome little computer for the 40 doller total investment

Answer (score 0):

The embedded graphics (GMA 3600) use some of main memory and there should be an option in the Intel Driver software to set how much to use. Grab at least the latest driver from the Acer site or preferably the latest from Intel. After installing there should be a setting in the display settings to adjust the memory used. Early drivers lacked this feature and had other problems as well.

[Acer AOD270 Driver Downloads](http://us.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/drivers/4040;-;AOD270)

[Intel GMA 3600 Downloads](http://www.intel.com/p/en_US/support/highlights/graphics/gma3600)